# How to access non Ethernet PHY from U-boot

Tags: ethernet, u-boot

I have a non ethernet phy interfaced on the MDIO bus of NXP MPC8308 controller. I want to access the phy registers from u-boot using 'mii' command, as of now the 'mii info' is not listing this device which has address '6' in the MDIO bus.

In the case of Ethernet PHY I would go to drivers/net/tsec.c and add the structure info in 'struct phy_info *phy_info[]' for the probe function to detect it.

A phy in question is CFP module which follows MDIO  interface definition in IEEE 802.3 Clause 45, http://www.cfp-msa.org/Documents/CFP_MSA_MIS_V2p2r06a.pdf

Any help is appreciated.

Greg

Comment: If this is a programming question please include the code you're trying to fix. Dumping a PDF spec sheet here is really not enough.

Comment: @tadman, sorry about that, the intention to share the spec sheet is to show the register detail of the phy which is not similar to regular ethernet phy. I have not started coding yet, rather looking for an entry point where to start.

Comment: If you haven't started programming this is premature for Stack Overflow and off-topic. Once you've got something sketched in, though, you can post your question looking for help. General advice is really hard to give in this question/answer format. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).